# Cloud Endpoints: Access Paramters in Servlet Filter

Tags: java, google-app-engine, guice, google-cloud-endpoints, servlet-filters

I'm trying to build an api with Google Cloud Endpoints.

As Cloud Endpoints does not provide authentication beside Googles own OAuth I try to build  my own. Therefore I want to access the parameters provided for the API (for example @Named("token") token) inside a servlet filter.

Unfortunately I cannot find any of the provided information inside the httpRequest. Is that normal? Is there a possibility to access the parameters?

I would appreciate if someone could help me!

**UPDATE:**

With the infos from jirungaray I tried to build an authentication using headers but ran into the same problem. Used a REST-Client to send some headers as I could not figure out how to do this with the API Explorer. Inside my filter I try to access the token from the headers:

```
@Override
public void doFilter(
        ServletRequest request,  ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    String authToken = httpRequest.getHeader(Constants.AUTH_TOKEN);
    ...
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

The reason why I try to do something like this, is that I'm using Guice for Dependency Injection and want my token to be injected inside another object.

With Guice I have the following Provider using the token to inject a FacebookClient (using the token) per request.

```
@Provides
public FacebookClient getFacebookClientProvider(@Named("fbToken") Provider<String> fbToken) {
    return new DefaultFacebookClient(fbToken.get(), Version.VERSION_2_2);
}
```

As described in the Guice wiki ([SevletModule](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/ServletModule#using-requestscope)) this uses a sevlet filter to get the information from the request.

Is there any solution to achieve this kind of DI with Cloud Endpoints?

Comment: If you want your question to get more views, you really should include [tag:java] as one of your tags. But you only have 5, and I'm not sure which one you'd prefer to remove. Probably [tag:guice-servlet].

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the advice. Just removed it a few minutes ago. Now it is back in!

Comment: You can get an idea of which tags to include by hovering over it, and seeing how many followers they have and how many questions they have. A tiny tag like [tag:guice-servlet] won't really help anyone to find your question, but many people do searches for recent posts tagged [tag:java]. So pick the *most popular* tags that are appropriate for your post. Now, if only I knew how to solve your question... :)

Comment: Interesting to know. What I thought was: with the java tag this question is just one in a million whereas in the not so popular tag it receives more attention by the people looking at that tag while having comprehensive knowledge about the topic.

Comment: Personally, most of the time I look at newest/active questions tagged Java and sometimes throw in a few smaller tags (like [tag:guice]) the only time older questions get seen is if someone has your exact problem.

Answer (score 3):

Philip, 
Yes, it does makes sense you are getting an empty request. Your endpoint calls are first handled by Google (they receive the API calls) and then those are processed and sent to a handler in your app. As this is all done in the background it's very easy to miss that your endpoints aren't actually getting the same request you sent, they get a completely different request sent from Google's infrastructure.

Even though your approach should work including tokens info in url makes them easier to sniff, even if you use SSL or encrypt your params the token is there in plain sight.
For what you are trying to achieve I recommend you include the token as a header in your request and retrieve that header by accessing the HTTPRequest directly on the endpoint, this is injected automatically if you include an `HTTPServletRequest` param in you endpoint method.

eg.

```
    public APIResponse doSomething(SomeComplexRquestModel request,
            HttpServletRequest rawRequest) {
}
```

If you still feel you should go with your original approach just comment and I'll help you debug the issue.

Comment: Generally I do not mind using a header field. I would even prefer it either. But for how to set this field using the generated client library?


When using this header field, is it possible to access it in the filter? The would make it easier to automate the authentication outside the endpoints.


Does this make the API explorer impossible to use as I cant' figure out how to set an header field in it?

Comment: I updated the question with more specific information about the real problem I want to solve. Perhaps this helps to find a solution.

Comment: What problem are you getting now? is the header null when you intercept the request with your filter?

Comment: Inside my filter I try to access the header with: httpRequest.getHeader("token");
but this always returns null on headers that are definitely set.